# Python Function doesn't work after importing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, discord, discord.py

I got a discord bot and I'm  trying to create a different file where I just have function that can handle different types of errors..

Example in the file **errorHandling.py**

```
async def on_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("heh")
        return
```

and in my main.py I just

```
from errorHandler import *
```

right?

and then

```
@Client.event
async def onerr():
    await on_error()
```

The bot is running, but when I type a command without its required arguments, nothing happens except that it gives me that long annoying error.
What am I doing wrong, or what did I forget?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @CyDevos 

`discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `on_command_error` for the errors that's raised because of commands. In the API References, it says:

> discord.**on_command_error**(ctx, error) 
> An error handler that is called *when an error is raised inside a command either through user input error, check failure, or an error in your own code*.

Also, there's no event named `onerr`, you can only override the existing ones.

```py
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("heh")
        return
```

This is all you have to do in `main.py` file.

## Reference

- [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_error)

Comment: @Nurgm I know that I just can type that in the main.py, but I want it in a different file.
I changed it to `on_command_error` , but now it tells me `TypeError: on_command_error() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given`

Comment: If you want it in another file, you should use [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html).